# Partial Reputation Credit

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, accepted-answer

Today, with all of your help, I managed to overshoot my 200 reputation daily limit. I was under the impression that accepted answer points are not counted to the 200 limit. I had one answer accepted today, but finished with a total of 208 points when I was expecting 215. I knew I had passes the limits because I had some votes listed with no reputation point gain. Here is a screenshot of my rep tab: [image: user's daily reputation summary]

Please note that [Division of Verses in Tanach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13524/759) and [Plural of "Nafka Minah"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12912/759) are both question that I asked and the upvotes on them would be worth 5 rep points each. The rest are my answers (except where obviously otherwise).

(Just to be clear I'm not as worried about the 7 rep points as I am the potential underlying coding probelm.)

Comment: From the picture, it seems like the system will simply not award "partial credit" for upvotes. That is, if someone upvotes your answer, you will either get 10 rep points or none at all. In your case, since you have one accepted answer, you cannot get over 215. But awarding you 10 points will give you 218. So instead, it doesn't award any points at all.

Comment: @jake But I could have gotten an extra 5 points to 213, but the upvotes on "Division of Verses in Tanach" which is a question I asked did not get counted.

Comment: Oh I see; didn't realize that was a question. My bad.

Comment: @jake Good point. I edited the question to make that clearer.

Comment: I've now alerted an SE employee to the existence of this post, and hope it may therefore get looked at sooner by someone who may know what's up.

Comment: @nick Can I get a little more explanation?

Comment: @DoubleAA woops, that should be [status-completed], reputation systems changed since then...notice that day has 219 now: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=20

Answer (score 2):

That is because the system **does not** work in Eastern Standard Time.

You did get 200 reputation in a 24 hour period:

[image: 30 rep]
[image: 170 rep]

Then as you can see after about 4pm eastern time the rep counting started again somehow.

And it counted 200 from the beginning of the day.

Comment: You want to say the maximum is 200 in any 24 hour period?

Comment: @DoubleAA No the maximum is 200 rep in one 24 GMT hour period.

Comment: But aren't those times in the picture GMT times? And FYI I was in Central Standard Time at the time this issue arose, not Eastern.

Comment: No, when the header says "208 today" it means UTC "today", not "local-time today".  Times shown are in UTC.

Comment: @MonicaCellio are you saying 'no' to me or to Naftali? Because I think we are agreeing (UTC=GMT)

Comment: @DoubleAA, sorry, I was speaking to Naftali, not you.